# How to add com.intellij.javascript.nodejs for create idea plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

Code include

```
import com.intellij.javascript.nodejs.interpreter.NodeJsInterpreterRef
```

When I'm trying to build it shows me this error message:

> Error:(4, 32) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow [the instructions](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/setting_up_environment.html) for setting up a development environment.

`NodeJsInterpreterRef` is provided by "JavaScript Support" plugin. You'll need to add the `JavaScriptLanguage.jar` to the classpath of your IDEA SDK. You should be able to find it in `plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/lib` inside your IntelliJ install directory.

Comment: thx, i know how add lib, but the doc didn't tell me where can find lib for add xd

Comment: `com.jetbrains.nodejs` is provided by NodeJS plugin. After installing to NodeJS plugin, it should be located in `plugins/NodeJS/lib/NodeJS.jar`

Comment: thx, so far for make a ts-node plugin by copy/paste ... https://github.com/bluelovers/idea-run-typescript